# SIGN Macro in C preprocessor

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

i tried writing a SIGN macro, that returns either - or +.

However it doesnt work like i expected it to, does anyone know how to do it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ABS(x) (((x) < 0) ? (-(x)) : (x))
#define MAX(x,y) (((x) < y) ? (y) : (x)
#define MIN(x,y) (((x) < y) ? (x) : (y))
#define DIFF(x,y) (ABS(x-y))
#define SIGN(x) (((x) < 0) ? (-) : (+))

int main(){

  int i = -45;
  int j = -5;
  printf("%c\n", SIGN(i) );

  return 0;
}
```

All the other macros work, but with SIGN i get an error

"error: expected expression before ')' token
 #define SIGN(x) (((x) < 0) ? (-) : (+))"

Comment: Do you want the macro to return the pre-processor tokens - and + or the ASCII characters `'-'` and `'+'`? That's quite a difference.

Comment: Please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us. All the other macros in the shown code is noise.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i didnt know that was nececary, i will do that in the future.

Comment: Btw to be picky, `0` should be treated as a special case.

Comment: @Umbranoctuna Well for such a small program as this one it's easy to disregard it. But once you get more complex problems that require more code to be shown, the less "noise" there is in the code will make it more easy to read and understand and follow, meaning it will be easier for us to help you. I also recommend you take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I tried to make a wise-ass answer like `printf("%c\n", ',' SIGN(i) (-1))` but to no avail :(

Comment: A “sign” like − or + is not a value in C. The sort of testing you are doing requires an expression that evaluates to a value. Values include numbers and characters (which are actually numeric values that are codes for the characters). Do you want the values to be the characters `'-'` and `'+'` or to be the numbers −1 and +1 or something else? What do you want the value to be when `x` is zero?

Answer (score 1):

There's two possible versions:

- `#define SIGN(x) ( (x) < 0 ? '-' : '+' )`
  This is the naive solution. It returns an `int` corresponding to characters `'-'` and `'+'`. It doesn't handle zero correctly. Likely it is just fine for beginner purposes.
- `#define SIGN(x) ( "+- "[((x)<=0) + !(x)] )`
  This is the over-engineered solution. It returns a `char` with value `'-'` or `'+'`, or in case of zero, a space `' '`. It uses boolean arithmetic according to this truth table:

  ```
  x     x<=0   !x
  pos   false  false
  neg   true   false
  0     true   true
  ```

  Adding the result of the two boolean expressions gives a value 0, 1 or 2, which is then used as look-up index in a string literal `"+- "`. Example:

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>

  #define SIGN(x) ( "+- "[((x)<=0) + !(x)] )

  int main (void)
  {
    int a = -123;
    int b = +123;
    int c = 0;
    printf("%c\n", SIGN(a));
    printf("%c\n", SIGN(b));
    printf("%c\n", SIGN(c));
  }
  ```

Comment: Wow!  Your over-engineered solution is great!  But if you're "just" trying to handle the zero case, you might be better off with a cascaded ternary operator: `((x)<0) ? '-' : ((x)==0) ? ' ' : '+'`.  Though both our solutions have the side effect of evaluating `x` twice, which is *bound* to lead into trouble.

Comment: @EddInglis More importantly, that code doesn't return a `char` but an `int`. And I'd say it has a bigger probability for branches.

Answer (score -1):

```
#define SIGN(x) (((x) < 0) ? ('-') : ('+'))

printf("%c\n", SIGN(i) );  // Will print either - or + followed by NewLine(\n)
```